# Places Autocomplete not returning locality (city) field

Tags: google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

Using places autocomplete address form , City for some locations not getting parsed

[image]
Using places autocomplete address form example as in google documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Expecting city to be populated for all the address, is there any way to have the city correctly populated for all the address?

Comment: What do you expect for the city?  The `place.address_component` of "postal_town" is Taby, is that what you want there?  Is this only for Sweden?  (different countries contain different address componets).

Comment: expecting stockholm in the city field, I am looking it to work worldwide, this is one address I have found its failing always

Comment: The result I get for that address has Stockholm as admin level 1 (state), the postal town is Taby.  Valhallavagen is a route.  Is there a reason you expect Stockholm to be its city?  Looking at where that result appears on a map (59.504004,18.083217), doesn't seem like it would be in the city of Stockholm. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/23xcqk7r/2/))

Answer (score 2):

The [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) you referenced is based on a typical address format which is applicable for some regions wherein the `locality` component represents the `city` part of an address.

For Sweden and UK, it is stated in the given [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform):

```
In the UK and in Sweden, the component to display the city is postal_town.
```

This means that the component that you should use to display the city is `postal_town` instead of the `locality` component.

The address ***Valhallavägen, Täby, Stockholm, Sweden*** correctly returns ***Täby*** as the municipality/city and note that it is within the Stockholm County as per this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_County#Municipalities).

That said, you have to modify the sample code to cater regions with different address formats to be able to display the municipality/city properly.

Hope this helps!